# Shared Contract WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, odata, wcf-data-services

There are a few ways to go about it. I can serialize the linq query, but the OSS project that allows expression tree serialization seems to be poorly supported.

Is there a more conventional way to do the following:

```
// Create the DataServiceContext using the service URI.
NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities(svcUri);
```

But without using the entity generation util. Basically I want to use something akin to the following pseudo code - note the shared IRepository contract:

```
new ChannelFactory<IRepository<MyEntity>>(myBinding, myUri).CreateChannel()
```

Also I prefer not to export the DataSet in it's entirety. I simply want my regular service to expose IQueryable operations. This way the IQueryable interface can be more strongly coupled to the business logic, as opposed to being a stand alone data service.

I'm receptive of OSS solution, but I am hoping for something that's stable, light-weight, active, well supported and frequently updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the repository pattern and a lot of custom business logic, Web API is probably your best choice for the short term. Getting better support for those two asks is very high on my priority list for WCF Data Services, but the fact of the matter is that we're pretty deficient there right now.

The limitations of Web API are going to be fullness of OData support, which may come with time. The limitations of WCF Data Services are going to be ease of business logic insertion/software patterns, which may be improved with time.

That said, if you have a read-only service the Reflection provider will do pretty much everything you want to do.

Comment: I considered it - but it seems a bit tough to use Web API for anything other than a web application. eg. WPF/Silverlight, or just inside some other service. Is my understanding off? Also do you have a link to the reflection provider? Read-only svc sounds like a good start.